# DES in hardware

Tags: des, cryptographic-hardware

Assuming that data is flowing in at a rate of n bits/sec and 1 iteration of DES can be performed in 1 clock cycle. Can we develop an expression for clock frequency, if DES were to be implemented using hardware?

Answer (score 1):

First about the required knowledge: obviously DES uses a 64 bit block. So a single DES operation permutes (encrypts or decrypts) 64 bits at a time. So this means DES is operating at 64 bits per cycle.

Now we want to encrypt DES at a ratio of $n$ bits per second. If we divide $n$ by $64$ then we get the number of required cycles per second to permute $n$ bits, which is the frequency (as $n$ is already specified as bits *per second*).

So in the end you're just left with $$f = {n \over 64}$$

Comment: Just another doubt, if it take a single clock cycle for 1 iteration, then doesn't DES take 16 clock cycles (considering 1 clock cycle per iteration), then shouldn't the equation be
                                      f = n/4

Comment: You wrote "*1 iteration of DES*". DES internally uses 16 rounds. If they meant rounds, then they should have asked for "(a single iteration of) *a round of DES*".

Comment: My bad, so if 1 round takes a single clock cycle, then does the equation n/4 hold true?

Comment: @saahil24 Yep, that should be it. You'd need a 16 times higher frequency, so divide by something that is 16 times less.

Comment: So, if 1 round takes a 1 clock cycle and some kind of hardware pipeline exists with 16 stages, the equation n / 64 is true.
Whereas, if the 16 stages are executed sequentially, the equation is n/4.
Is that logic correct?

Comment: Yep. Sounds right to me.